# JSON Object Loop

Tags: php, json

How to get instagram_business_id (id) if its there? Enable to get it, undefined index instagram_business_id error

```
    $pages = '[
  {
    "access_token": "",
    "instagram_business_account": {
      "id": "123"
    },
    "name": "Page Name",
    "id": "XXX"
  },
  {
    "access_token": "",
    "name": "Page Name2",
    "id": "XXX"
  }
]';

Loop
foreach($pages as $page){

}
```

Comment: try `$pages = json_decode($pages);`

Comment: Try this after the `$pages = json_decode($pages)` : `foreach ($pages as $key => $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->instagram_business_account)) {
        $instagram = $obj->instagram_business_account;

        if (isset($instagram->id)) {
            echo $instagram->id;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code
$res = json_decode($pages, true);

print_r($res[0]['instagram_business_account']);

Comment: Same issue Undefined index: instagram_business_account

Comment: I used the below code, Pls let me know if your output is different
<?php

$pages = '[
  {
    "access_token": "",
    "instagram_business_account": {
      "id": "123"
    },
    "name": "Page Name",
    "id": "XXX"
  },
  {
    "access_token": "",
    "name": "Page Name2",
    "id": "XXX"
  }
]';

$res = json_decode($pages, true);

print_r($res[0]['instagram_business_account']);

?>

Comment: There is no output only error

Comment: what error is coming??